# Design Automation for Revit (DA4R)

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

Is it possible to use dynamo scripts within Forge? I want a user to be able to create a dynamo script, upload this and execute the script on revit models in Forge.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible today.

Comment: Could this be elaborated with reference to "official" documents to back it up?